# python / opencv3 double thresholding (up and down)

Tags: python, opencv

I'm new to python and opencv. I want to load an image (grayscale) and do some special thresholding. I want to keep brightness values between 20-30 as is and make zero (or 255) all other pixel's values. I mean pixels with brightness value below 20 and over 30.

I made some tests with `inrange` but no luck. I also tried the following but it only does half the job:

```
ret,img = cv.threshold(img,30,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY)
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `cv2.inrange()` module. The minimum and maximum value can be placed for any image.

In your case since you are using a single-channeled image you can perform something like this:

```
masked = cv2.inRange(im, 20, 30)
cv2.imshow('masked',masked)
```

In your question you have mentioned that `cv.threshold()` does half the job. You need to do it twice and subtract the resultant to get the full job done!

```
ret1, img1 = cv2.threshold(im, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
ret2, img2 = cv2.threshold(im, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow('double_threshold', img1 - img2)
```